# VirtualHost/.htaccess - redirect from .com to .se/en not working/ignored (Polylang?)

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, rewrite, wordpress, apache2

I'm trying to redirect `domain.com` to `domain.se/en`, but it just won't work. It's like another rewrite or redirect is happening to `domain.se/sv` **before I get the chance**. I've tried multiple VirtualHosts configs and `.htaccess` variants without success. `domain.com` uses an A record that points to the same IP as `domain.se` (main domain) does. I suspect the WordPress plugin **Polylang** might be rewriting the URL or causing a redirect before I get the chance.

My `.htacces` currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain.com.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.se/en [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and my VirtualHosts config looks like this: (Note that both `.no` and `.fi` also wrongly redirects to `.se/sv`)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        RedirectPermanent / http://domain.se/en
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.fi
        ServerAlias www.domain.fi
        RedirectPermanent / http://domain.se/fi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName domain.se
        ServerAlias www.domain.se
        ServerAlias domain.no
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what it looks like in Chrome Dev tools Network section when I try to go to `domain.com`:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools - Network Tab - Showing redirect]

I flushed DNS cache locally and in Chrome before visiting the domain.

Comment: "My .htacces currently" - I assume that's just a typo? It should be `.htaccess`. Do you have any additional `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Are `/en` or `/sv` physical subdirectories? Note, you should include the `R` flag in your `RewriteRule` (although it will implicitly trigger a 302 in this instance since you have specified an absolute URL.)

Comment: Also, try adding a `R=307` in your `RewriteRule` directive - do you see the 307 status in the network traffic?

Comment: 1. Just a typo here 2. Thank you! Redirect 307 / http://domain.se/en worked! If you add your comment as an answer I'll "accept" it :)

Comment: The `R=307` is not a solution - that was just to help with debugging. Simply changing that would not actually change anything. I also didn't suggest changing that redirect to a mod_alias `Redirect` - which would appear to do something different to what you require (if we are talking about the same thing)? (In fact, mixing mod_alias `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` is not recommended.) It's not clear what is going on here. My guess is that "something else" has changed, or there was some caching issue (although you say you cleared all _local_ caches)?

Comment: If you are adamant that your changes solved this then please document your solution as an answer, which you can later accept. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. WordPress seem to be the culprit in this header. I do not know your project structure, so I would suggest either two approach to troubleshoot the issue:

`Header always edit Location` in your VirtualHost configuration, requires `mod_headers`. This will always edit the header *after* any modification made by application, i.e., Zend, WordPress, Spring, etc.

`wp_redirect`, from [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179077), should help with your troubleshooting without touching server configuration. This is probably ***not*** the elegant solution to your question but this is a function that you could use to debug application.

Comment: But unless WordPress is generating additional `.htaccess` files(?!) then the above Apache directives should override anything that WordPress (ie. PHP) would be able to do?! WordPress shouldn't even be getting a look in?

Comment: Some of my applications integrate with `Zend`, `PHP`, and `WordPress`, and runs on `httpd` with `mysqld`. Sometime I need to update `siteurl` in WordPress database to direct for correct domain. I'm not 100% knowledgeable about Zend or WordPress but this issue occurs _after_ integration.